# ASP.NET Core 6: how to bring the console window to the foreground upon launch

Tags: asp.net-core

After creating a new project using the "ASP.NET Core Web App" template, when I run the project, I want the console window to automatically be brought to the foreground. Since I'm mainly developing a web API, I don't want the browser to launch (which I've done in launchsettings.json), but **do** want the console window to show.

I've verified that this is the default behaviour when creating a .NET Core 6 **Console app**, yet I can't find the settings responsible for this desired behaviour.

Comment: What you mean is that when the .net6 project you create is started, a console will pop up. You want it to display the information in vs without popping up the console, right?

Comment: No, I want the console window to display in the foreground. Each time I do a CTRL-F5 run, the app (which is a console window) launches, yes, but the window is in the background, so each time I have to click on it if I want to monitor its output and verify it started up correctly. A small deal, I admit, but if it does what I want in a default Console app template, how can I get it to do the same for an ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@BCA, I found the option to do exactly this:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved easily just by changing a debug setting. It may be a little bit different in old versions of Visual Studio!

> VS2022

**1. Open Launch Profiles window:**

[image]

**2. Select relevant profile from opened window and change Launch browser setting(uncheck it)**

[image]

**3. Save the change if there is any Save button. and run the project.**

Comment: That's not what the question asked, but thanks for the effort. I have already made it so the browser is suppressed, but what I want is the console window to automatically come to the foreground.